# How to use same unit test for different implementations in python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, automated-tests, tdd, python-unittest

I am developing multiple functions that answer a same problem but using different algorithm.

So the same input for all functions should generate the same output, that's why I wnted to use the same unit tests instead of having to create multiple tests with the same logic.

I was using the **Python unittest framework**, and I wanted to use an *abstract test class* to have the generic tests defined with a *function* variable so that I could just instantiate that generic function with the one I want to test in another normal test class. But it seems I can't instantiate the *function* variable in the child class.

So here is an example abstract class with generic tests for multiple functions.

```
class AbstractTestCase():

    def test_generic_input_one(self):
        result = self.function("input 1")
        self.assertFalse(result)

    def test_generic_input_two(self):
        result = self.function("input 2")
        self.assertTrue(result)
```

And here you would have a specific test class for the `function_a` that inherits the generic tests from the `AbstractTestCase` class and that implements its own.

```
class TestsFunctionA(AbstractTestCase, unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.function = function_a

    def test_specific_input(self):
        result = self.assertTrue(self.function("specific input"))
        self.assertTrue(result)
```

I am pretty sure it can be done, but I can't seem to find an example to see how to implement it. I would like to avoid code duplication.

What should be the simplest and best way to do it ?

Comment: Could you elaborate on this statement a bit more: "I wanted to use an abstract test class but it does not accept any kind of variable, so I can't pass the function."?

Comment: I have edited the question, my goal was to have the generic tests defined with a _function_ variable in the abstract class so that I could just instantiate that generic _function_ with the one I want to test in a child test class. But it seems I can't instantiate the _function_ variable in the child class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have been looking for it and got a couple of example like:

- [Eli Bendersky's Python unit testing: parametrized test cases](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/02/python-unit-testing-parametrized-test-cases)

But what helped me the most was [vegard's answer](https://twitter.com/vegard_no/) about making a class factory which would take parameters and create the TestCase accordingly

> The function takes the parameters of the parameterised test case and the actual TestCase class can refer to them without any problems.

Here is an example, take a `foo.py` file with:

```py
import unittest

def make_test_case(x):
    class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
        def test_foo(self):
            self.assertEquals(x, 1)

    return MyTestCase

class ConcreteTestCase(make_test_case(1)): 
    pass
```

Then run the test(s):

```
python -m unittest -v foo
```

Basically this is very flexible and adapted really well to my usecase.

Comment: This will work even if you're using pytest. You could just leave out the inheritance.

Answer (score 3):

Basically you need to parametrized you tests with function.

For `unittest` you can use [ddt](https://github.com/txels/ddt)

```
@ddt
class ProblemTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_specific_input(self):
        self.assertTrue(function_a("specific input"))

    @data(function_a, function_b)
    def test_generic_input_one(self, function):
        result = function("input 1")
        self.assertFalse(result)

    @data(function_a, function_b)
    def test_generic_input_two(self, function):
        result = function("input 2")
        self.assertTrue(result)
```

Alternatively you can use just plain OOP:

```
class AbstractTestCase(object):

    def test_generic_input_one(self):
        result = self.function("input 1")
        self.assertFalse(result)

    def test_generic_input_two(self):
        result = self.function("input 2")
        self.assertTrue(result)

class TestsFunctionA(AbstractTestCase, unittest.TestCase):

    def function(self, param):
        return function_a(param)

    def test_specific_input(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.function("specific input"))

class TestsFunctionB(AbstractTestCase, unittest.TestCase):

    def function(self, param):
        return function_b(param)

    def test_another_specific_input(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.function("another specific input"))
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer! --- 
I think ddt is deprecated but pytest seems to have the same feature with annotation. For the plain OOP example: it's very nice! I was wondering if it would handle multiple inheritance. I am going to check that with your example. What do you think of the answer I found?

Comment: Multiple inheritance will work fine. IMHO the solution with class generation is unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Oh there's something that I have found out, you can't have `unittest.Testcase` inherited to the AbstractTestClass otherwise the tests would run in it and fail.

It should be something like `TestFunctionA(AbstractTestCase, unittest.TestCase)` instead to have the tests run with the sub class.

Answer (score 2):

I came here searching for a way to test multiple implementations of the same function. My use case is testing student's submissions of different search algorithms that are all fed the same test data and should return the same results.

Sylhare's answer was easy to adopt but it does not hurt to share so here is how:

```
import unittest

def function_a():
    result = ...
    return result

def function_b():
    result = ...
    return result

def make_test(function):

    class TestImplementation(unittest.TestCase):

        def test_foo(self):
            self.assertEquals(function, 1)

    return TestImplementation

class TestImplementationA(make_test(function_a)): 
    pass

class TestImplementationB(make_test(function_b)): 
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

**Given** a structure

```
├── README.md
├── requirements.txt
├── test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── two_sum
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── base_test_suite.py
│       ├── test_brute_force.py
│       └── test_two_pass_hash_table.py
└── two_sum
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── brute_force.py
    └── two_pass_hash_table.py
```

**And** there are brute-force and two-pass hash-table solutions (functions called `two_sum`) in the corresponding files in `two_sum` module.

**And** base_test_suite.py

```
class TestTwoSum:
    def __init__(self, unittest, two_sum_func):
        self.two_sum = two_sum_func
        self.unittest = unittest

    def test_it_returns_indices_of_two_numbers_that_add_up_to_target(self):
        # given
        numbers = [2, 7, 11, 15]
        target = 9

        # when
        result = self.two_sum(numbers, target)

        # then
        self.unittest.assertEqual(result, [0, 1])
```

**And** test_brute_force.py

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from test.two_sum.base_test_suite import TestTwoSum
from two_sum.brute_force import two_sum


class Test(TestCase):
    def test(self):
        case = TestTwoSum(self, two_sum)
        case.test_it_returns_indices_of_two_numbers_that_add_up_to_target()
```

**And** test_two_pass_hash_table.py

```py
from unittest import TestCase
from test.two_sum.base_test_suite import TestTwoSum
from two_sum.two_pass_hash_table import two_sum


class Test(TestCase):
    def test(self):
        case = TestTwoSum(self, two_sum)
        case.test_it_returns_indices_of_two_numbers_that_add_up_to_target()
```

**Then** one can run `python -m unittest` which would run the same unit test for different solutions of the two sum problem.

Comment: So, for every test case in `TestTwoSum` there are two more than call it with different implementations. That's not really maintainable.